# Unity build on IOS no matching function for call to 'il2cpp_codegen_write_instance_field_data'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity compiler error in 2022.2 LTS and 2023.01

The code builds and compiles in both the editor and on Macos but fails in Xcode when building for IOS throwing
no matching function for call to 'il2cpp_codegen_write_instance_field_data'

This error started to happen when I tried to update our project to the 2022.2 LTS version of Unity.

In build settings and player settings, IL2CPP is activated as the Backend Scripting.
any hint ?

Comment: I have the same error with Unity 2022.3.0f1 but not with Unity 2022.2.5f1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got past this by deleting the Builds/iOS folder.